# Crawlable AJAX app WITHOUT server rendering

Tags: javascript, ajax, seo, web-crawler, isomorphic-javascript

***Question:*** *Is it possible to make SPA crawlable without server rendering with help of HTML5 History API `pushState`?*

I have found contradictory meanings. Can you support or refute one of them?

1. [*YES*, it's possible to make SPA crawlable w/o server rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437815/does-html5modetrue-affect-google-search-crawlers/32782081#32782081).

   The only explanation I found is - when Google crawler goes through `<a href="site.com/go">` it subscribes to [`onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate) and waits you'll trigger HTML5 History `pushState`. After you get all async content, you trigger `pushState` and crawler start crawling.

   *Do really Google knows how to subscribe onpopstate events?*
2. *No*, that impossible. I came to the same conclusion, the same is said in [this article](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-1-introducing-pushstate/). It says that `pushState` is a replacement of [hashbangs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started) to make the same URL for both user and crawler.

**P.S.** If it's impossible with `pushState`, are there any other acceptable ways?

Comment: This is kinda borderline.  But how SEO does and does not work, and how particular search engines operate in regards to this, is more appropriate over on [webmasters.se]

Comment: @Will sorry, can't follow you. Explain in more details please

Comment: This doesn't appear to be about programming for SEO, it appears to be about how SEO works and how Google operates.  This appears to be on topic on [webmasters.se] but not here.  Read the warning on the [seo tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info).

Comment: @Will got it, thanks

Comment: @ErikHonn please take a look at this question, hope you can give me an answer