# Google not crawling my pages even using history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, seo, html5-history

I read a lot on SEO compatibility with google crawler before starting my new project. And everything tends to say that Google know execute javascript, and so can render my template. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31437815/does-html5modetrue-affect-google-search-crawlers).

But it seems that the crawler never execute my javascript, and the templating with some api's data isn't done. (I seen that after using the "fetch as google tool")

I started my router like this

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, hashChange: false});
```

And so route are handled like this:

```
Backbone.history.navigate(url, { trigger: true });
```

So I probably miss something somewhere but where ?

Comment: It will execute javascript, but not all of it.

Comment: @Stan Is there some guidelines or whatever to understand the limitations that exist ? I see many website well reference using this method, there must be a trick

Comment: @AllanRaquin FWIW, in spite of Google publishing that piece a while ago claiming it crawls SPA, my experience didn't align with that. If curious, I wrote a few quick blogs posts about it: http://mcranston18.github.io/angular-seo-pt1/, http://mcranston18.github.io/angular-seo-pt2/, http://mcranston18.github.io/angular-seo-pt3%20copy/